# segmentation fault in C during scanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to scan in an integer to use for my program. However my program gives me segmentation fault during compilation this is the section that is giving me the error:

```
int main(void)
{
    int totalHeight=0, floorWidth=0, amountOfStories, amountWindowForTop, amountWindowForMiddle, amountWindowForBottom, windowHeight, middleWindowWidth, topWindowWidth, bottomWindowWidth, minimumHeight, minimumWidth;

    char topFloorWindowContent, middleFloorWindowContent, bottomFloorWindowContent, windowBorder, floorBorder;

    int tempMax;

    printf("please enter how many stories your building would like to have: ");
    scanf("%d",&amountOfStories);
    minimumHeight=amountOfStories*6+1;
    while((totalHeight<minimumHeight)||((totalHeight%amountOfStories)!=1))
    {
        printf("please enter the totalHeight (minimum %d): ",minimumHeight);
        scanf("%d",&totalHeight);
    }
    printf("please enter how many window building would have for top floor: ");
    scanf("%d",amountWindowForTop);
    printf("please enter how many window building would have for middle floors: ");
```

now my program after compile only runs to the scanf on the amoutWindowForTop
after I enter in the value for that it just gives me segmentation fault I have no idea why. Because I am not using pointers so why is it giving me that error？everything seemed in order for me 
this is the output

```
please enter how many stories your building would like to have: 5
please enter the totalHeight (minimum 31): 31
please enter how many window building would have for top floor: 2
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: thank you guys I got it now so stupid of me to miss that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `&`,

Line

```
scanf("%d",amountWindowForTop);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &amountWindowForTop);
//---------^
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed & in

```
scanf("%d",amountWindowForTop);
```

this must be

```
scanf("%d",&amountWindowForTop);
```

Cause of error is
**&** is called **address of operator** so missing it in scanf means where are you put your value means address is required because it specify the address of variable where we have to keep the value. 
segmentation fault error is generally we get whenever their is any problem related with address.
Hope useful for you.

Comment: you might try this: www.hemingwayapp.com :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed `&` in

```
 scanf("%d", amountWindowForTop);  
            ^Place & operator
```

Comment: OMG that is just I know I need & but if u put it in your face u don't notice wow just wow thanks so much though

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `&`

```
scanf("%d",&amountWindowForTop);
           ^
```